# Carrierwave upload to Amazon s3 with wrong url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I am using Carrierwave/RailsAPI to upload images to Amazon S3.

Media is uploading correctly and into the correct folder and bucket.

PROBLEM:
Carrierwave is saving the url to the image and the thumb in the wrong format.

The correct url is:
https://region.amazonaws.com/bucket/folder/filename.jpeg

Carrierwave saves
https://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/folder/filename.jpeg

My configurations follow:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_provider = 'fog/aws'
  config.fog_credentials = {
      :provider               => 'AWS',
      :aws_access_key_id      => "AWS_KEY",
      :aws_secret_access_key  => "SECRET_KEY",
      :region                 => 'us-west-2'
  }
  config.fog_directory  = "bucket"
end
```

---

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  storage :fog

  def store_dir
    "folder/"
  end

  def default_url
    "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
  end

  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_fill => [150, 150]
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

  def filename
    DateTime.now.strftime('%Q') + ".jpeg"
  end

end
```

Help Appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Both forms of the URL are valid. From the [Amazon docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html#access-bucket-intro):

> Amazon S3 supports both virtual-hosted–style and path-style URLs to
>   access a bucket.
>
> - In a virtual-hosted–style URL, the bucket name is part of the domain name in the URL. For example:
>
>   - http://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com
>   - http://bucket.s3-aws-region.amazonaws.com.
>
>   In a virtual-hosted–style URL, you can use either of these endpoints. If you make a request to the http://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com
>     endpoint, the DNS has sufficient information to route your request
>     directly to the region where your bucket resides.
> - In a path-style URL, the bucket name is not part of the domain (unless you use a region-specific endpoint). For example:
>
>   - US East (N. Virginia) region endpoint, http://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket
>   - Region-specific endpoint, http://s3-aws-region.amazonaws.com/bucket
>
>   In a path-style URL, the endpoint you use must match the region in which the bucket resides. For example, if your bucket is in the South
>     America (Sao Paulo) region, you must use the
>     http://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/bucket endpoint. If your bucket is
>     in the US East (N. Virginia) region, you must use the
>     http://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket endpoint.